# How to get IP address of vCenter Server from a vCenter Plugin (using vsphere web client sdk)?

Tags: vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

I want to get IP address of vCenter Server from my plugin. But from `UserSessionService`, I only can get host name of vCenter Server (something like `vc01.example.local`). Is there anyway to get IP address of vCenter Server? Thank you!

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: From the plugin, we want to run a script in a different machine, and the script need vCenter IP as its input to interact with the vCenter Server

Comment: Are you writing a custom plugin?

Comment: Yes, we are creating a custom plugin using vSphere Web Client SDK